# problem with lost reference with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, reference, tree

i am trying to do a tree of children and fathers, but i am losing the reference to the chilndrens when their born in a function, here a will put an example with dogs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Dog{
    int id;
    double amound_of_bones;
    int *bones;
    int *gifts;
    struct Dog *other_dog; 
}Dog;

void have_children(Dog *father){
  Dog pancho;
  pancho.id=5;
  pancho.amound_of_bones=1544.5;
  (*father).other_dog=&pancho;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



Dog pepi;
have_children(&pepi);
printf("the dog id: %d, have %f bones\n",(*pepi.other_dog).id,(*pepi.other_dog).amound_of_bones);

printf("the dog id: %d, have %f bones\n",(*pepi.other_dog).id,(*pepi.other_dog).amound_of_bones);



return 1;
}
```

and here is the strange ouput:

```
the dog id: 5, have 1544.500000 bones
the dog id: 0, have 0.000000 bones
```

you going to see that the first output go well but the other lost the reference, i dont know how to resolve it

Comment: Tip: `*(x).y` can be writte as `x->y`

Comment: sorry i forget some part of the code

Comment: Why do you have the same `printf` line twice in your program?

Comment: because the first printf give the correct output,but the second give other result,even when it's the same printf

Comment: Ah, the first `printf` call must be using the memory address that used to be `&pancho`, which is now pointed to be `pepi.other_dog`. That is probably why the second `printf` prints something else, even if it is doing the same thing as the first one. This is because your program is causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as stated in the answer.

Comment: and how i can solved this?, because i don t know other way to create children for a obj, because this will be recursive

Comment: I have now written an answer for you, which also shows how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `have_children`, the variable `pancho` is a local variable. This means that the lifetime of the variable is only as long as the function `have_children`. When that function returns, the variable `pancho` ceases to exist and the memory will no longer be reserved for that object. This means that the memory can used by some other part of your program, which will cause the memory to be overwritten.

Because you assign the address of `pancho` to `pepi->other_dog`, that pointer will be pointing to an invalid object after the lifetime of `pancho` ends, i.e. after the function `have_children` returns. This means that `pepi->other_dog` will become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Dereferencing such a dangling pointer causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The reason why the first `printf` call works is probably because the memory of the object has not been overwritten yet. The second `printf` call gives you a different result, probably because the memory address was used internally by the first `printf` call for something else, so it got overwritten by some other value.

To fix this undefined behavior, you must ensure that the lifetime of the object that you point to does not expire too early. For example, you can use the function `malloc` instead. That way, the lifetime of the object will last until you call `free`.

Here is an example of how you can rewrite the function `have_children` to use `malloc`:

```
#include <assert.h> //this header is required for the "assert" macro used below

void have_children(Dog *father){
    Dog *pancho = malloc( sizeof(Dog) );
    assert( pancho != NULL );
    pancho->id = 5;
    pancho->amound_of_bones = 1544.5;
    father->other_dog = pancho;
}
```

The `assert` macro is not required, but it is generally a good habit to check the return value of `malloc` to make sure that it is not NULL.

Answer (score 2):

`Dog pancho;` is a local variable in `have_children()` function. When function returns, that memory is freed. You saved a pointer to a memory which is no longer valid. This behavior is undefined.

Comment: yes sorry i never call the function, and how i can resolve that problem

Comment: @mrpepo877: In the function `have_children`, if you allocate memory for `pancho` as a local varible, then the lifetime of this variable will be only as long as the lifetime of the function. If you want the lifetime of the variable `pancho` to be longer (so that you can make pointers point to it without the pointers becoming invalid), then you can use `malloc` instead. That memory will remain allocated until you call `free`.

Comment: like this  
 `(*father).other_dog = malloc(sizeof(Dog));
    (*father).other_dog = &pancho;`?

Comment: @mrpepo877: `Dog pancho;` should be changed to `Dog *pancho = malloc( sizeof( Dog ) );` Then you can write in the last line `father->other_dog = pancho;` However, in the other two lines, you must use `->` instead of `.`, because `pancho` is now a pointer and not the object itself.